# VB or operator on int32 and int

Tags: vb.net

whats do Or operator in Vb do when it is applied as follows
eg

```
Dim returnValue As UInt32
Public Const RMA_VC_RET_NULL_PTR_PARAMETER = 1

returnValue = returnValue Or RMA_VC_RET_NULL_PTR_PARAMETER
```

what does the 3rd statement do?

Answer (score 1):

Or is the equivalent of the C# `|` operator.  It is a binary or operation.  It will return the number represented in returnValue with the least significant bit being potentially changed to 1.